# I am trying to create my first personal website and I am having trouble with sizing my image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create my first personal website and I am having trouble with sizing my image, I need help resizing my image.

I tried everything but it doesn't seem to change. I have tried changing the width and changing the positioning.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');
body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    
}
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*navbar*/
.navbar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
  translate: -50%;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar *{
    display: inline;
}
.nav-link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-nav{
    justify-content: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 #fff, -2px 0 #fff, 0 2px #fff, 0 -2px #fff,
    1px 1px #fff, -1px -1px #fff, 1px -1px #fff, -1px 1px #fff;
}

/*main display text*/

#coverPage{
    background: url(https://wallpapers.com/images/hd/dark-shades-of-purple-j1bf61qb3t5kkk6h.webp)fixed right top;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    

    
}
.main-display{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 20px black,
    -2px 1px 30px black;
}
#title{
    font-size:3em;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.SE{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.bball{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 5000;
}
.gym{
    font-size: 17px;
}
/*About me */
#about-me{
    background-color: gray;
    margin:0;
    min-height:90vh;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

.about-title{
     top: 50%;
    left: 54%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
   
}

#about-line{
    border-top: solid #5468FF 2px;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translate(-110%,100%);
    width: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}
.about-me-p{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50;
    right: 65%;
    border: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
}
.slider-container {
    position:absolute;
    top: 112%;
    margin-right: 77%;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50;
    right: 8%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Center the container both horizontally and vertically */
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
}

.slider-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 48rem;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.slider{
    display: flex;
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    overflow: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 3rem -0.75rem hsla(0,0%,0%,0.25);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;

}
.slider img{
    width: 40%;
    height: auto;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    scroll-snap-align:start;
    object-fit:cover;
}
.slider-nav{
    display: flex;
    column-gap:1rem;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 1.25rem;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
.slider-nav a{
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.75;
    transition: opacity ease 250ms;
}

.slider-nav a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
#button-about{

    display: inline-block;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    will-change: box-shadow,transform;
    background: radial-gradient( 100% 100% at 100% 0%, #89E5FF 0%, #5468FF 100% );
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgb(45 35 66 / 40%), 0px 7px 13px -3px rgb(45 35 66 / 30%), inset 0px -3px 0px rgb(58 65 111 / 50%);
    padding: 0 32px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    transition: box-shadow 0.15s ease,transform 0.15s ease;
    :hover {
        box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgb(45 35 66 / 40%), 0px 7px 13px -3px rgb(45 35 66 / 30%), inset 0px -3px 0px #3c4fe0;
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    :active{
        box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 7px #3c4fe0;
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }
    
}
#Projects{
    background-color: darkred;
    min-height: 90vh;
    padding: 2px;
}

#project-title{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(35px);
    margin: auto;
}
.expense-container{
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
  
}
#expense-title{
    color: white;
    transform: translate(23%,5%);
}
#expense-P{
    color: white;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translate(50%,10%);
}
#LLC-title{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(25%)
    translateY(45px)
    
}
#about-LLC{
    color: white;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translate(200%,50%);

}

#socials{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    transform: translateY(150px);
}
#github{
    color: white;
}
#linkedin{
    color: white;
}
#github:hover{
    color: black;

}
#linkedin:hover{
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Personal</title>
     <!--  bootstrap and aos  -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nadir.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNavAltMarkup" div>
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">projects</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <section id="coverPage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="main-display" >
                        <h1 class="display-1" id="title" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">NADIR ESMAIL</h1>
                        <h2 class="SE" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">software developer</h2>
                        <h1 class="bball" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Basketball fanatic</h1>
                        <h1 class="gym" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="2000">Gym enthusiast</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!--About me page-->
    <section id="about-me">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="about-title">
                    <h1 id="about-me-h1" class="display-5">About</h1>
                    <p ID="about-line"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="about-me-p" data-aos="fade-right">
                    <p>I am an aspiring software developer with a deep passion for the world of coding and technology. My goal is to create innovative software solutions that can make a positive impact on people's lives. </p>
                    <button id="button-about" class="button-85" role="button">Learn more</button>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-container" data-aos="fade-right">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <div class="slider">
                <img id="slide-1" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc_v1C7acGncFzSAhtTRW4EaNFxxyI8q_ndFEpKLheUZvLvvsDKKmq6oYIBxaMlJIIgbIdHQYqnmojJ_ErDR4emkT3cSaND4yfG2bcJAhcPvC_0EpOd2lAzKYspS-FeG11F8aA4Kz5khlSotbXHNgOJl=w627-h835-s-no?authuser=0" alt="">
                <img id="slide-2" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc-DjxqUW6zaxnQpSufba2cTctSEwdHrCfEmLrc4V4otFAkpzE1uV7cJua1A_E7rkDIS40vno_gGdjadVKeHTPhnbSxTuSe47wjhmrNClHbqk0fRtPIrw4Et7Yn8YbTAsCYGBFx-yVece8fD-Y2says-jIeB5oeEzkG1Dxps8jip0ngWAO-CQDLKN7TD8IbrYdNJ22uM-Qa0bfuPKAjkAFd5Or6FFS34Pq12YhQI3zYjmUAAKKVzWwHVv2lJGQAmI4JGTpCuBe4dY9iNnnZAEYpcPhIWSMsR7l5gonGimu-sa3ImNvQFQ_C7QjMM4_qFMs0KTzHHnlPD3GXoFOaVMNHonipa0WZ-lZXqnAQc4F0e9raUF5dK5A0zSTVhkdsQ9xMS0qkd6Avdz12Gzo8mcYlZ5ClNbMOi3HhB31pO5AEah_yg2SauzX9e24HrT9TN02Ymm8yZarCj41ZrDGn6PkTrHRFLLAgWTJ3d2A_rMhsNcv8w4vnnc0---uhsL3Vf03YjLcWG9hW5h3sm5k3ADggGfJwon8hwCbNiky9cO_LDALrMXbswaLjf6wvCPsSE9kF1jdbavgP-9Kn6VyOsapyXFFJmWwaXTB3ObuK8a7IgLXdr0sqVfFSh7YOQwtj0K7Fq9mWs8ZcQeXNwH4rZ1nsTruQBHw8FQRjc1o688h4WOZSHkDMI2xUAsFcth8uHFWc-_l2kxIHe2i4M3tZJAyoOeDv4UJURoVTeDC0vkj5jFNFMRiXkO1PhLYl4O9LhKnjHEFjATOjny9OGihOZf61RndUKwAwA1XX-BlaBpmI6LLrTynHYiDAMw7AbxdfgUrY1JiFGLP95dI2AbPqI7KZMqWRphl5vpPJy-LXxMAoVfy6rvPKoHV5-p1n2ndTbEaXSXhthS0Dk3mEIw4pd0yRiUg=w1170-h879-s-no?authuser=0" alt="">
                <img id="slide-3" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc9PdCfCoiIqVoceQ5pIpFTVbZ7nHKIG-Y8yU6XAqC_hTbCYn20czzSVMymQSdHX2yeMR4gNuGL6h4joST7BlDEXeWP-IyhJxaC9V7EecKYeZRbgN_2wxQa9LQwm696AA0C9IzCxIpd-RfjACCglvqU2=w1086-h1440-s-no?authuser=0" alt="">

            </div>
            
                <div class="slider-nav">
                    <a href="#slide-1"></a>
                    <a href="#slide-2"></a>
                    <a href="#slide-3"></a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </section>

 <section id="Projects">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="project-title">
                <h1 id="project-title">Project</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="expense-container">
            <div id="project-pictures">
                <img #id="expense" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AIL4fc91uARDyJKShHXGc-SZMrdo1_wqlEbsuasmK5ZWrouoA8WNUHR7X32B2HFcu9AKGL5kDaR_hROZkqmsvuRO0A1Re0XlEd_6N0fCHrbp1DciRlh6qPuWV8vMrQBmesF7G7eq_DV7Zq5_ItjI2zcuEemeb00Qbn9nRiWnoTx9ceyw64YKIvkLcmfu_2PIbymNUnfvFwwmj_RsyGv8S9beFUij7vYL6hH_kJ_zWoh32GyD12drddsPf6jwTW-mwXmy3F5-FjHKlMZWAtQjftMowuqrj3fXhy0jDAIUyv4V8mlFgHTPD1P6YaIEqlMkZbLrs1MOo6ArQhnyTSrXe-zS1OgOE4gcubYfKUnyTXkgL5lDIVGthjOYp_RBemNVXStoaqtrXzWc4Z7D99meNn7FWVZO1hSbC3Cfp2Miw3CQ_yPH1Xs7d1AiHBsb-6ldrbmrZjwb4t8Z-NkV6ynsIfgqEWTUfr0AIzFD2gBc_NP8FyhdGejFz7BPb_WPKXWsCd3SnCqnaCsroAcnSScmHSiNkWHZu4AT_NgVPKX1u3AVZe8wwuSLQWiM33pDhRBFlKrUpbg4Rkf1jtTamzfj4LhDkIQcfGVcHVmfXbbiXiwCZV3fYOCiXB8vubEZvcYrY8HHXHBjDsfN7_4vqia9iiW7rvpHnPfMd4--xYj01wRnOf13cEYLQgOfOVnVB0_JKaYpnRvdbraqlTDtsjgisT_YbBIodFjuMhOvn6REmGB0XjPYkmGY7BjQP9Qaa70CYg2jDDn2TPImxhZdwm1455W_xwZ8Z65-5unaopvRMi5Uiu9Fyu-9KeFPwlQmI7eSnzylde2g9qSCbLLfqtF9ZRLOWTvQvDvuQzvpqTvHEz1FE61fgX7uPfwK70C1tUZo3SHrCjm5e95wcTfU4jgQrc3L0gxapQ=w2560-h1440-s-no?authuser=0" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="expense-about">
                <h1 id="expense-title"> Expense Tracker</h1>
                <p id="expense-P">The Expense Tracker project I developed using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript is a comprehensive web application that empowers users to effectively manage their finances with ease and precision. This feature-rich tool enables users to track their expenses efficiently by allowing them to input and categorize expenses.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="LLC">
                <h1 id="LLC-title">LLC Website</h1>
                <p id="about-LLC">I had the privilege of working in a collaborative team of three to create a professional and sophisticated website for a law LLC. Using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and JavaScript, we designed an engaging and user-friendly website featuring three key pages: a captivating cover page, an informative services page, and a detailed about me page</p>

            </div>
            <div id="socials">
                <a id="github" href="https://github.com/EsmailNadir">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-github fa-beat-fade fa-xl"></i>
                </a> 
                <a id="linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/nadiresmail/">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-beat-fade fa-xl"></i>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 </section>

  <!--  bootstrap and aos js  -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="nadir.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8c2adfc9c1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make it a small square shape to put it next to text. Please help, and if you have any other suggestions please feel free to share.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?

Comment: @j08691 its bootstrap 5

Comment: That is probably you have use Aos animation on body tag, so one solution could be setting overflow-x: hidden would wok for you.Let me know whether this solution work for you or not :)